# I am trying to config my own map server with mapnik mod_tile and apache no tiles are generated and i get the following errors

Tags: maps, ubuntu-12.04, openstreetmap, psql, mapnik

```
I started this
renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
got this
renderd[1620]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[1620]: Initiating reqyest_queue
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (7):
-> ;[renderd01]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (14):
-> ;[renderd02]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (33):
-> ;** config options used by mod_tile, but not renderd **
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (42):
-> ;[style2]
iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (49):
-> ;** config options used by mod_tile, but not renderd **
renderd[1620]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[1620]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[1620]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[1620]: Parsing section default
renderd[1620]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[1620]: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[1620]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[1620]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[1620]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[1620]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
renderd[1620]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
renderd[1620]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[1620]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[1620]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[1620]: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[1620]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[1620]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[1620]: config map 0:   name(default) file(/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml) uri(/osm_tiles/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[1620]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[1620]: Created server socket 5
renderd[1620]: Renderd is using mapnik version 2.0.3
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[1620]: Starting stats thread
/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/inc/entities.xml.inc:9: parser warning : PEReference: %layers; not found
%layers;
        ^
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/inc/entities.xml.inc:9: parser warning : PEReference: %layers; not found
%layers;
        ^
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/inc/entities.xml.inc:9: parser warning : PEReference: %layers; not found
%layers;
        ^
/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/inc/entities.xml.inc:9: renderd[1620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': XML document not well formed: 
Entity 'datasource-settings' not defined (encountered in file '/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml' at line 4066)
parser warning : PEReference: %layers; not found
%layers;
        ^
renderd[1620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': XML document not well formed: 
Entity 'datasource-settings' not defined (encountered in file '/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml' at line 4066)
renderd[1620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': XML document not well formed: 
Entity 'datasource-settings' not defined (encountered in file '/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml' at line 4066)
renderd[1620]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': XML document not well formed: 
Entity 'datasource-settings' not defined (encountered in file '/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml' at line 4066)
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 8, number 1
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(8) xml(default), z(0), x(0), y(0)
renderd[1620]: Received request for map layer 'default' which failed to load
renderd[1620]: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 8 closed, now 0 left
```

I am using http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/ for refrence. any help and I have tried building a map server from packages had a sock problem so switched here the sock problem can be rectified using 
sudo mkdir /var/run/renderd
sudo chown mayank /var/run/renderd

Comment: problem was with the osm.xml it was resolved by using the avialaible python module to create an osm! thanks though!! :)

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer with some more details.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem following the same article. I got rid of the `PEReference: %layers; not found` errors by running the following command from `~/src/mapnik-style` : `python generate_xml.py --dbname gis --user YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_PASSWORD --host localhost --accept-none --world_boundaries "/usr/local/share/world_boundaries"`

Now getting `error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'  encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in Layer at line 37 of '/home/julian/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml'` Will update if fixed.

Comment: Fixed everything. See my answer for how I got everything up and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a drama! The article at [switch2osm.org](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/) could do with some updating. Anyway, to fix the above errors:

Go to `~/src/mapnik-style` and run

```
python generate_xml.py --dbname gis --world_boundaries "/usr/local/share/world_boundaries" --accept-none
```

This will reset your mapnik style configuration and fix those `%layers` errors.

NOTE: Your `world_boundaries` folder location might be different to mine. Find yours by typing `find /usr -type d -name "*world_boundaries*" -print`

Next, you may have errors like `An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'shape'`. This is because renderd has the wrong plugin directory. To find yours, type `find /usr -type d -name "*mapnik*" -print` you'll get something like one of the following (and maybe a few others we don't care about):

- /usr/lib/mapnik
- /usr/local/lib/mapnik
- /usr/lib64/mapnik

Go to the folder you found and check that it has the `input` dir. Mine has nothing else in it. This is your renderd mapnik plugin directory. Edit your `/usr/local/etc/renderd.conf` file to change the plugin directory to this location.

For reference, my final `renderd.conf` file contained:

```
[renderd]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=4
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
URI=/osm_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/home/julian/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
```

I deleted all the commented lines in `renderd.conf` because they didn't seem useful and were creating the syntax errors at the top of the renderd output.

Also, my `~/src/mapnik-style/inc/datasource-settings.xml.inc` file contained:

```
<Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
<!-- <Parameter name="password"></Parameter> -->
<!-- <Parameter name="host"></Parameter> -->
<!-- <Parameter name="port"></Parameter> -->
<!-- <Parameter name="user"></Parameter> -->
<Parameter name="dbname">gis</Parameter>
<!-- this should be 'false' if you are manually providing the 'extent' -->
<Parameter name="estimate_extent">false</Parameter>
<!-- manually provided extent in epsg 900913 for whole globe -->
<!-- providing this speeds up Mapnik database queries -->
<Parameter name="extent">-20037508,-19929239,20037508,19929239</Parameter>
```

I think that's everything you need to get rid of these errors. If not, please comment and I'll do my best to update this answer.

Comment: Thanks @gabssnake Glad someone finally got some use out of it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a configuration problem. I know you already solved your problem, but maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

Make sure to double- or triple-check your configuration. I had
    osm2pgsql_projection "&srs%900913;"
instead of
    osm2pgsql_projection "&srs900913;"
in the ~/src/mapnik-style/inc/settings.xml.inc and got the same problem as described above. Removing that unintentional % fixed it for me.

Comment: iniparser: syntax error in /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf (7):
Is due to a problem in your renderd.conf. You can post yours here if you need some help.

/home/mayank/src/mapnik-style/inc/entities.xml.inc:9: parser warning : PEReference: %layers; not found
%layers; and all related errors are due to the non configured osm.xml u specified in your conf for rendered u can generate it by pthon file generate_xml.py in mapnik-style folder. If there are any other problems let me know.